# Using Google Apps to handle customized after hours auto responses to support based email inbox

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-apps-script, google-apps-email, google-apps-for-work

THE SETUP:
Our company has a primary support email that all of our clients use to generate helpdesk tickets.  It is a google apps inbox using helpdesk@%our primary domain%

Our ticketing support auto pulls from this inbox and then moves into "all mail" or rather "archives" it in Google lingo.

THE NEED:
I want to have an after hours auto responder (only once per after hours period from 6:01pm-8:59am the following day) that immediately fires off an auto responder that lets the email sender know it is an after hours ticket.

THE QUESTION:
How to implement a time-based auto-responder in Gmail (on a Google Apps domain)?

Comment: Does a customer fill out a form?  Send an email?  During the day the customer calls in?  But at night the customer will visit a website?  Whatever the initial action is, you'll need an installable trigger.  It can be a time based trigger, that runs every 15 minutes, and searches your email.  It can be an "On Form Submit" trigger that runs as soon as the Google Form is submitted.

Comment: Because tool recommendations are off-topic here, I edited the question so that it might remain open (it got 3 close votes already). If you want to ask the original form of your question, see [softwarerecs.se]

Comment: @SandyGood The user submits an email, and this inbox is polled by our ticketing software that then generates a ticket.  I just want to send them a notification after hours that we will be looking at the ticket the next business day.

Answer (score 1):

There is no setting in the Gmail UI for a time based auto response.

The [Email Settings API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/) does allow you to enable, disable, change, and poll the current state of the autoresponder.

Comment: Apparently, there is the new [GMail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/) now.